# Can't boot into Ubuntu 17.10 default (lowlatency) kernel

Tags: 17.10

After upgrading it from 17.04, now I can't boot into Ubuntu 17.10 with default boot option (lowlatency kernel). However if I go into "advance option" and choose to boot with generic kernel option, I can boot it normally.

How to fix this issue? Or if there is no way to fix this, how to set generic kernel as default option?

These are my boot options:

```
> sudo update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-16-lowlatency
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-16-lowlatency
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-16-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-16-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-37-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-37-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-58-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-58-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
```

Comment: You have to provide more information - what error does the low latency kernel give you ?

Comment: how to get those error?

Comment: boot the low latency kernel , what happens ?

Comment: it's a black screen constantly flashing with green OK and white text, the last line is `[  OK  ] Started GNOME Display Manager.`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

To set the `generic` kernel as the default option,

Edit `/etc/default/grub`

Change`GRUB_DEFAULT=0` to `GRUB_DEFAULT="1>2"`

Note, menu options are numbered starting with `0`.

So, the above says on the first menu, select the 2nd option ("Advanced Options" in my case) and select the 3rd option on the submenu ("-generic" kernel in my case).

Your menu values may vary depending on the options in your Grub menu.

Run `update-grub` to save these settings.

I also commented out `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT`, and set `GRUB_TIMEOUT=3` so I can see the grub menu at boot in case I have problems in the future.